# Undefined behaviour in a PSRAM read memory transaction

Tags: memory, timing, sram

I am reading the datasheet of a PSRAM (available [here](http://download.micron.com/pdf/datasheets/psram/128mb_burst_cr1_5_p26z.pdf)). Looking at the timing diagram for burst reads (page 10, figure 8), there is a "undefined behaviour" for a half-cycle on the `DQ` pins, before the data words `D0`, `D1`, `D`2 and `D3` arrive.

What could be the cause for this undefined state of the `DQ` pins? Is this common for PSRAMs?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you can't count on what the pins are. They could be high, low, hi-z. This is common for memory parts that have a latency of more than one state.

To answer @stevenh below, it says that before the unknown time you can count on it being hi-z. During the unknown time is what I said above true.

Comment: Yes, but the latency (3 clocks) is already shown, and this comes after that.